# If $R$ is IBN, do we have $K\oplus R^{n}\cong R^n\implies K=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, direct-sum, free-modules

> Let $R$ be a (unital) ring with the invariant base number property, and let $K$ be a left $R$-module such that $K\oplus R^{n}\cong R^n$ for some $n\geq 0$. Is it true that $K=0$?

I know that this is true if for example $R$ is commutative, because then we can tensor with $R_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and reduce it to vector spaces. Does it still hold if we only assume the IBN-property?

Comment: Rings with the property that $R^{n}\cong R^{n}\oplus N \implies N=0$ are called stably finite. In Lectures on Modules and Rings by Lam, Prop. 1.8 shows that any stably finite ring has IBN, but the converse is not true. Jeremy's answer gives such an example.

Comment: @Zeek thanks for providing the proper terminology, this makes it easier for me to look into it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in general, even for $n=1$.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}\langle x,y\mid yx=1\rangle$, the ring generated by two noncommuting variables $x$ and $y$ subject to the single relation $yx=1$. This ring has a basis $\{x^iy^j\mid 0\leq i,j<\infty\}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ with multiplication of basis elements easily deducible from the relation (just cancel as many instances of $yx$ as possible).

There is a surjective ring homomorphism $\varphi:R\to\mathbb{Z}$ with $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)=1$ and so $R$ has the IBN property (a ring has IBN if it has a homomorphic image with IBN).

Right multiplication by $x$ is a left $R$-module homomorphism $\alpha:~_RR\to~_RR$  and is surjective since it has a right inverse given by right multiplication by $y$. Since $_RR$ is projective, $\alpha$ splits and so 
$$_RR~\cong~_RR\oplus\ker(\alpha).$$

But $\ker(\alpha)\neq0$, since $(xy-1)x=0$, so $xy-1\in\ker(\alpha)$.

Comment: Thanks again! :)